# multiple selection databound listbox stored as parameter for sql datasource update

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, listbox, sharepoint-2010

I have a databound listbox that autoposts for each selection.
I would like to be able to store all selected values in a parameter (@Product_Type2) and use in a SQL update query. I can store the listbox values as a string in a textbox(TextBox1) but cannot get the query to use all values.This is in a SharePoint asp and cannot use code behind. I have included a code snipit.

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" id="ListBox2" DataTextField="ProductDesc" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDropdownProd_2" DataValueField="Product_Type2" AutoPostBack="True" SelectionMode="Multiple">
</asp:ListBox>
<br />
<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
                var values = "('";

                var selected = $("[id*=ListBox2] option:selected");

                selected.each(function () {
                    values += $(this).val() + "','";
                });
               document.getElementById('TextBox1').value =(values)+'zzz' + "')";
                return false;
            });

    </script>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox1" Width="255px" Height="334px" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:TextBox>

<asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSourceDropdownProd_2" runat="server" ...
 SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT sdt.[Product Type2] AS Product_Type2, pd2.ProductDesc, pd2.line
FROM            dbo.sportsCD_Data_TEST AS sdt INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Dim_Product_Type2 AS pd2 ON sdt.[Product Type2] = pd2.Product
ORDER BY pd2.line" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">

    </asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSourceDropdownProd_3" runat="server" ...
SelectCommand="SELECT        [Sales Pro Number] AS Sales_Pro_Number, [New Price] AS New_Price, [Product Type2] AS Product_Type2, [Percent], Dollar
FROM            dbo.sportsCD_Data_TEST

WHERE       ([Product Type2] in (@Product_Type2))"  
UPDATE [sportsCD_Data_TEST] SET

 [New Price] = CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), CAST([Sell Price] AS float) * (CAST(@Percent AS float) / 100) 
                         + CAST([Sell Price] AS float)+ CAST(@Dollar as float)) ,  [Percent] = 0, [Dollar] = 0 

WHERE       ([Product Type2] in (@Product_Type2))" <SelectParameters>

        <asp:controlparameter ControlID="TextBox1" PropertyName="Text" Name="Product_Type2" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:parameter Name="Percent" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Dollar" Type="Decimal" />

        <asp:parameter Name="Product_Type2" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

</form>
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to feed your update statement a string (like "('A','B','C','zzz')"), so your update statement is reading it as a single string rather than parsing it. If you want it to parse what's in the string, you'll need to use dynamic SQL. Alternatively, you could rewrite the code to take a comma-delimited input, split the input, then update based on that.

Comment: Could you help me parse this into a usable form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way you could do it.

If your database already has a string-splitting function, use that. If it doesn't and you're able to add one, pick one that's suitable for you. Here's some ideas for how to make one: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings (if you can trust your input to be only alphanumeric with commas and spaces then the XML one should work fine). e.g.

```
-- USE [DatabaseName]
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

Next, change your jquery function to look something like this:

```
    $(function () {
            var values;

            var selected = $("[id*=ListBox2] option:selected");

            selected.each(function () {
                values += "," + $(this).val();
            });
           document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = values;
            return false;
        });
```

You just want to feed your update statement something like ",A,B,C", no quotation marks necessary. Then make your update statement look like this:

```
UPDATE sCDT
SET [New Price] = CAST(1.0 * [Sell Price] * @Percent / 100 + [Sell Price] + @Dollar AS DECIMAL(10,2))
    , [Percent] = 0
    , [Dollar] = 0
FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML(STUFF(@Product_Type2, 1, 1, ''), ',') T -- insert appropriate string-splitting table-function, the STUFF is to get rid of leading comma
JOIN [sportsCD_Data_TEST] sCDT ON sCDT.[Product Type2] = T.[Item];
```

Comment: I am getting a null value for the textbox1document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = values

Comment: I am getting a null value for the textbox1
document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = values.

I am able to view the value in the textbox but when updating with just 
UPDATE  dbo.sportsCD_Data_TEST
SET [New Price] = @Product_Type2 I get NULL values.

I also need to be able to allow for just one selection since another query depends on this one.

Thank You for help

Comment: One selection would work fine with this query, I believe. If you're getting a null value, is it because the textbox isn't being passed to the query? e.g. `<asp:parameter Name="Product_Type2" />` should be `<asp:ControlParameter...` and reference the textbox.